# Правильное ли условие

Tags: php

Есть самописный Point of Sale софт для аптек на PHP. Для того, чтобы кассир не смог продавать больше, чем количество препарата, которое есть на складе, делаю так:

```
include('../connect.php');
$nl = $_POST['nall'] ;
$a = $_POST['invoice'];
$b = $_POST['product'];
$c = $_POST['qty'];
   if($c > $nl) {
      echo "<div align='center'><font color='red' 
      style='font:bold 22px 'Aleo';'>Внимание: Вы не сможете расходовать больше чем остаток. Сейчас будете перенаправлены' </font> </div><br> "; 
      echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=" . 
      $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">";
   exit; 
   } ?>
```

Как видно по коду, если продаваемое количество препарата (переменная $c) *БОЛЬШЕ* количества остатка на складе (переменная $nl), то вывести ошибку. Но если, допустим, количество препарата на складе 10 шт. и кассир собирается продавать тоже 10 шт., то всё равно выводит ошибку, что нельзя расходовать больше чем остаток.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно написать условие, чтобы когда кассир собирается продавать больше, а не ровно - вывести ошибку?
Сделал так, и всё точно заработало:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id= :userid");
$result->bindParam(':userid', $b);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    $nall= $row['qty'] ;
    if ($nall<$c) {
    echo "<div align='center'><font color='red' 
      style='font:bold 22px 'Aleo';'>Внимание: Вы не сможете 
расходовать больше чем остаток. Сейчас будете перенаправлены' </font> 
</div><br> "; 
      echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;url=" . 
      $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">";
   exit; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Данные с POST запроса, которые ожидаются, что будут числами - необходимо перевести к типу `int`, т.к. полученные данные придут с типом `string`

Comment: Я делал так но при таком раскладе кассир может расходовать даже больше чем остаток )

Comment: @AlexStassov кто из представленных переменных в вопросе - кассир? и кто такой тогда  $nl?

Comment: $nl = остаток на складе $c= количество которое хочет продать кассир

Comment: @AlexStassov читаем вопрос: `продаваемое количество препарата (переменная $nl)....` ........... `....чем количества остатка на складе (переменная $c)` ..........не определился?

Comment: Исправил ! прошу прощения за невнимательность. Кстати var_dump($_POST['qty'], $_POST['nall']);
выдаёт вот это string(2) "25" string(3) "210"

Comment: @AlexStassov  ну так правильно.... проблема в том, что ты сравниваешь строки, а нужно числа. условие значит верное, а вот типы данных неправильные

Comment: и как поступить ? просто превратить стринги в числа ?

Comment: @AlexStassov да..

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что всегда надо сделать проверки параметров прежде чем использовать их.
Всегда надо следить за типами ваших данных, это можно сделать разными способами, один из них intval, хотя и можно просто умножить переменные на единицу `$_POST['nall']*1`. И тип измениться.

```
include('../connect.php');
$nl = intval($_POST['nall']) ;
$a = $_POST['invoice'];
$b = $_POST['product'];
$c = intval($_POST['qty']);
   if($c > $nl) {
      echo "<div align='center'><font color='red' 
      style='font:bold 22px 'Aleo';'>Внимание Вы не сможете 
расходовать больше чем остаток. Сейчас будете перенаправлены' </font> 
</div><br> "; 
      echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=" . 
      $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">";
   exit; 
} ?>
```

А про остольных переменных не могу сказать, я не знаю для чего они нужны вам и какие значения в них.
intval делает явное преоброзование типа в int.
Подробно можете посмотреть [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php)

Comment: Но в документации php написано ведь В случае, если вы сравниваете число со строкой или две строки, содержащие числа, каждая строка будет преобразована в число, и сравниваться они будут как числа.

Comment: @AlexStassov, вы ни когда не должны доверять данным пришедшим из вне. Это $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_COOKIE, $_REQUEST все данные из вне.

Comment: Спасибо понял. Но как мне быть чтоб решить данную проблему. Всё равно после того как превратил в числа проблема остаётся прежней (Остальные переменные нужны дальше я весь код не привел просто

Comment: до этой строки `if($c > $nl) {` выведите данные и посмотрите нормально пришли или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Работает всё верно! даже если переменная $c равна строке то всё равно условия выполняется верно. Может у вас в post чтото не то приходит?

```
<?php 
    $c = "10"; // количество препаратов
    $nl = 10; // на складе
    
    if($c > $nl) {
          echo "<div align='center'><font color='red' 
                      style='font:bold 22px 'Aleo';'>Внимание Вы не сможете 
                расходовать больше чем остаток. Сейчас будете перенаправлены' </font> 
                </div><br> "; 
       exit; 
    } 
    
    ?>
```